# Get closest form element value by name with Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get the value that I am getting with the following jQuery code with JavaScript?

**jQuery code snippet:**

```
$('.add-to-cart-btn').on('click', function() {
  qualifyingProductVariantId = $(this).closest('form').find("input[type='hidden'][name='id']").val();
});
```

As I was trying with **javascript code:**

```
function getVariant(this){
  var qualifyingProductVariantId  = this.querySelector('[name="related_id"]').value;
  alert(qualifyingProductVariantId);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
document.querySelector(selector).closest
```

You can refer to [here](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

There isn't HTML in your question, so perhaps my answer won't work.

Could you try:

```
document.querySelector('.add-to-cart-btn').addEventListener('click', ev => {
    const eform = ev.target.querySelector.closest('form')
    // you have the form, you can continue search...
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest equivalent to your jQuery based script would be something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.add-to-cart-btn').forEach(b=>b.onclick=()=>
  console.log(b.closest('form').querySelector("input[type='hidden'][name='id']").value)));
```